# Logout in Spring Authorization server (acting as Identity broker) with Federated Identity Provider

Tags: spring-security, federated-identity, spring-authorization-server

I'm new to using Spring Boot and Spring security; I'm trying to build an Identity broker with Spring security Oauth2 components. The broker handles all the authorization, token and logout requests from my SPA(React) clients. It then delegates authentication to an external Identity Provider (Keycloak) which supports [RP initiated logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html).

I'm following the [Federated Identity Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/eae6630599c139ddab3a1e9060a124fd47224059/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/security/FederatedIdentityIdTokenCustomizer.java#L62-L71) provided in this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/106).

The login works fine without any issues. As for logout, only the local session within the Identity broker is cleared. There is no request firing to the Identity provider's `end_session_endpoint`.

I did some reading and found the following code in the Spring security [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-logout).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
            .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
            );
        return http.build();
    }

    private LogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler =
                new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository);

        // Sets the location that the End-User's User Agent will be redirected to
        // after the logout has been performed at the Provider
        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}");

        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }
}
```

I configured the `LogoutSuccessHandler` to the Security filter chain. However, it is not being invoked when logout request is issued to the `end_session_endpoint` of my Identity broker `/connect/logout` from my React SPA. The parameters to the request are `id_token_hint` and `post_logout_redirect_uri` which is a Uri in my React app registered with my Identity broker (Authorization Server).

After some debugging, I noticed that the `OidcLogoutEndpointFilter` configured by default, handles the logout request at `/connect/logout` and checks for a `post_logout_redirect_uri` in the parameters and redirects to it.

How can I implement the RP initiated logout through my Identity broker in this scenario?
The expected behavior is when I logout from my React app, the Identity broker issues logout request to the Federated Identity Provider, clears the local session and redirects back to my app.

I have found several questions and issues around this topic, but none that fits this specific case. Please point out to me if this has already been answered and I failed to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting a solution that worked well for me.

After some reading, I found from the spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/protocol-endpoints.html#oidc-logout-endpoint), and `oidcLogoutEndpointFilter` that the `logoutResponseHandler` is configurable. It is basically an implementation of the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` interface.

In my custom implementation of this interface, first, clearing out the local session associated with the requesting client by invoking the  `SecurityContextLogoutHandler`. Then, constructing a redirect url using the `end_session_endpoint` of the external IdP, `id_token` issued by the external IdP, and the `post_logout_redirect_uri` from the original logout request and sending a redirect response back to the browser `(https://external-idp.com/connect/logout?id_token_hint=''&post_logout_redirect_uri='')`. Then, I configured this implementation as the `logoutResponseHandler` to the `oidc.logoutEndpoint` in the `SecurityFilterChain` for authorization server.

This way, the user's session in the Identity broker is cleared as usual, and the session in the external IdP is also cleared by sending a request to its `end_session_endpoint` from the user's browser.

Comment: I'd have to see some code to be sure, but it seems like a plausible approach. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Can you please share your custom implementation of the interface?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll say that there's possibly a good enhancement request in this question. If you look at `OidcLogoutEndpointFilter`, `logoutSuccessHandler` is not currently customizable. If it were, you could potentially configure `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` directly with `OidcLogoutEndpointFilter`.

In the meantime, you might need to consider chaining together a redirect flow yourself. If you don't set a `postLogoutRedirectUri` on the `RegisteredClient`, the `OidcLogoutEndpointFilter` will simply redirect to the `/` endpoint. You can implement that endpoint in a custom way and call the `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` manually yourself to trigger the RP-initiated logout of the federated provider.

**Note:** I don't yet have a sample that demonstrates this, but it could be nice to add this to our existing sample.

Comment: Thanks @steve ! I agree that it would be nice to have this configurable.

However, for the time being, I came up with a solution that works well for me. I'll post the solution as an answer. Please review and let me know if it has any flaws or can be improved.